# Processing WCF Fault Message

Tags: .net, wcf, fault

I am consumimg WCF web services via .NET/C# using Visual Studio 2017.  The following is the detail section of a fault:

```
<detail>
    <FatalException>
        <errorCode>E 0008</errorCode>
        <message>The business policies have been violated.</message>
        <responseCode>FATAL_INT_ERROR</responseCode>
        <validationErrors>
            <associatedSeverity>0</associatedSeverity>
            <attributeName>userld, process number</attributeName>
            <attributeValue>NNNN******NNNN</attributeValue>
            <errorCode>B 014</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>Duplicate Transaction</errorMessage>
            <objectName>ObjABCD</objectName>
        </validationErrors>
        <validationErrors>
            <associatedSeverity>0</associatedSeverity>
            <attributeName>userld, process number</attributeName>
            <attributeValue>NNNN******NNNN</attributeValue>
            <errorCode>AB 015</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>Refer to procedure guide</errorMessage>
            <objectName>ObjXYZ</objectName>
            </validationErrors>
    </FatalException>
</detail>
```

I was able to access the message "The business policies have been violated" with this code snippet:

```
catch(FaultException e)
{
string ERRORMSG = e.Message
}
```

I can't figure out how to get to the validationErrors array data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the code generated on the client side for the type that matches the expected fault. You would then need to use that to type the FaultException you want to catch e.g.

```
catch(FaultException<YourExceptionType> e)
{
  ... // Access your custom fault properties
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultexception-1?view=netframework-4.8) for `FaultException<TDetail>` for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your service uses a fault contract to wrap the details of the error. The Fault contract is a custom type. We can capture this strong type using the Try-Catch statement on the client-side.
In addition, the Fault Contract and Service Contract are shared between the client and the service, namely, these are known on the client-side. Service contracts and fault contracts are also generated by adding service references.

```
Try
{
}
catch (FaultException<FatalException> e)
            {
                FatalException fe = e.Detail;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: With `FaultException<FatalException>` I get **"The type or namespace FatalException' could not be found"**. I was able to find code that allows me to get to `<errorCode>E 0008</errorCode>`: `var detail = e.GetType()?.GetProperty("Detail")?.GetValue(e, null); ERRORCODE = detail?.GetType()?.GetProperty("errorCode")?.GetValue(detail, null) as string;` But I still can't figure out how to get to the `validationErrors` array. I assume some property value used with GetProperty must be used.

Comment: Which way do you use to call the WCF service? Are you using the client-proxy class to call the service? we should guarantee that the Fault Contract is shared on the client-side, just like the service contract.